# Android Bitmap Height and Width equaling -1

Tags: android

I have a 200 x 30 png-24 image that I am trying to load into my application. I've already imported multiple other pngs using this same method and they all work fine. However when this png is loaded it causes the bitmap returned to have a -1 width and height. The bitmap wont draw.

```
mGameover=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.gameover);
```

The line where I load in the resource. It probably doesn't help. I have tried cleaning my project and it still doesn't work. Also tried recreating the png but it still isn't working.

any ideas?

Comment: would you mind posting a link to the image so I could try and see if I have similar results?

Comment: -1 width and height means there is an error trying to decode that picture. Have you tried converting it to a regular png?

Comment: Sorry photobucket was being slow. http://i17.photobucket.com/albums/b64/Infinitegde/Public/gameover.png    and I tried converting down to png-8 but it also didnt work. those were the only option photoshop gives me for png

Comment: Acually Vector was right! Photoshop didn't want to save it properly. I tinkered a bit and got it to work. Post it as an answer and Ill give you rep and mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When bitmap factory returns -1,-1 in the bitmap for the width and height of the Bitmap it means that Android was unable to decode the resource. - Answer by Vector

Answer (score 1):

Nope, according to BitmapFactory doc, null value is returned if Android could not decode the resource. If bitmap is not null then it has most certainly be decoded.
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources, int, android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)